# How to enable DirectX 11 engine in LightningChart WPF to plot lots of data points

Tags: wpf, performance, charts, real-time, directx-11

I'm trialing still LightningChart v.7.0.2. I saw a demo to plot 1 billion points with LightningChart, [Billion points real-time charting demo](http://arction.com/billion_data_points_visualization).

I made a similar my self and I'm only able to get only 200-300 millions points and then it starts to badly slow down.

Arction demo on that page is running fine with 1200 million data points with my new NVidia GTX750. But not my own app. I'm wondering why. Maybe it's because it shows Hardware 9 as renderer. How can I enable DirectX 11 renderer? Or is there another setting that needs to be modified?

I already set line width to 1, and disable palette-driven coloring, some help there, but still I'm wondering what's the catch here.

Comment: Why don't you directly ask in their forum ? http://forum.arction.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pinging me by mail.

The DirectX 11 engine is default engine in LightningChart v.7.1 onwards. In v.7.0, LC uses DirectX 9 engine by default.

Engine can be selected manually like this:

**chart.ChartRenderOptions.DeviceType = AutoPreferD11;** //Prefers D11 HW - D9 HW - D11 SW (WARP) - D9 SW

**chart.ChartRenderOptions.DeviceType = AutoPreferD9;** //Prefers D9 HW - D11 HW - D11 SW (WARP) - D9 SW

and then there's options to force hardware or software modes in D9 and D11.

So please update your trial version to 7.1, and you can run your app with over billion data points.

Comment: Tx! I updated sw. You're too modest, 1 billion points, you say! I had 2.68 billion until out-of-memory. Awesome.